# Update BigQuery table with an array of objects where some of the values may be null

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I need to update an exisitng table in BigQuery with custom array of objects. I am using Node.js with this client library: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery

Let's say I have a table with two "STRING" type columns to update it I use the following code.

```js
import BigQueryConnection from "./utilities/BigQuery.connection";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    country: "Germany"
  },
    {
    id: "2",
    country: "France"
  },
]


  const tableId = 'test_dataset.test_table';
  const mergeQuery = `
  MERGE ${tableId} t
  USING UNNEST(@rows) s
  ON t.id = s.id
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
    id = s.id,
    country = s.country
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, country) VALUES (s.id, s.country)`;

  const options = {
    query: mergeQuery,
    params: {
      rows: data
    },
    types: {
      id: 'STRING',
      country: 'STRING',
    },
    useLegacySql: false
  };


  const response = await BigQueryConnection.bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
  const job = response[0];

  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults(job);
  console.log(rows)
```

It works well but from time to time my data comes like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    country: null
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    country: "France"
  },
]
```

it always gives the following error. `Error: Parameter types must be provided for null values via the 'types' field in query options.`
Even though the parameter types are provided the error persist. Am I missing something or this just doesn't work with Big Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the script on my side with the following structure :

[image]

The `query.js` file :

```js
'use strict';

function main() {
    // [START bigquery_query]
    // [START bigquery_client_default_credentials]
    // Import the Google Cloud client library using default credentials
    const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
    const bigquery = new BigQuery();

    const data = [
        {
            "featureName": "featureReal",
            "jobName": "jobReal",
            "pipelineStep": "pipelineReal",
            "inputElement": "inputElementReal",
            "exceptionType": "myExceptionType",
            "stackTrace": "stackTraceReal",
            "componentType": "componentTypeReal",
            "dagOperator": "dagOperatorReal",
            "additionalInfo": "info Real"
        },
        {
            "featureName": "featurePSG",
            "jobName": "jobPSG2",
            "pipelineStep": "pipelinePSG",
            "inputElement": "inputElementPSG",
            "exceptionType": "myExceptionType",
            "stackTrace": "stackTracePSG",
            "componentType": "componentTypePSG",
            "dagOperator": "dagOperatorPSG",
            "additionalInfo": "info PSG"
        }
    ]

    // [END bigquery_client_default_credentials]
    async function query() {
        const tableId = "`gb-poc-373711.monitoring.job_failure`"

        const mergeQuery = `
          MERGE ${tableId} t
          USING UNNEST(@rows) s
          ON t.featureName = s.featureName
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET 
            jobName = s.jobName,
            pipelineStep = s.pipelineStep
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (
                featureName, 
                jobName,
                pipelineStep,
                inputElement,
                exceptionType,
                stackTrace,
                componentType,
                dagOperator,
                additionalInfo
            ) 
            VALUES (
                s.featureName, 
                s.jobName,
                s.pipelineStep,
                s.inputElement,
                s.exceptionType,
                s.stackTrace,
                s.componentType,
                s.dagOperator,
                s.additionalInfo
            )`;

        // For all options, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query
        const options = {
            query: mergeQuery,
            // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
            location: 'EU',
            params: {rows: data}
        };

        // Run the query as a job
        const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
        console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

        // Wait for the query to finish
        const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

        // Print the results
        console.log('Rows:');
        rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
    }

    // [END bigquery_query]
    query();
}

main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

It worked correctly on my side.

- The `rows` parameter is correctly passed to my query
- I also tested the merge query on `null` fields and it worked correctly

The `package.json` file :

```json
{
  "name": "bigquery-node-client-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

To have the details and reference documentation for the options, you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job).

Comment: changing the options object throws Typescript error as probably `createQueryJob` method expect different object as a parameter. I changed the code to use `createJob` but this time I get error: `ApiError: Query parameter 'rows' not found at [3:16]`

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer with corrections. I added the async bloc and used `createJob` method

Comment: thanks for the response but the code still gives the same error. Does it work on your end? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Yes it worked in my case but I tested it with a `SELECT` query and not `MERGE`, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I now tested the same code with an `update` query and it worked.

Comment: I edited my answer to share all the code and structure used on my side, I also shared the `package.json` code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I appreciate the time you took! Have you tried the query with paraemeter? e.g `USING UNNEST(@mydata)`? Also have you tried to merge data where some values are `null`? My problem seems to be conected with these 2 specific cases

Comment: I tested the merge query with the `rows` param and I also tested the merge query on null fields and it worked correctly on my side. I updated my answer with all the details. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Mazlum Tosun I finnaly got i working on my side. I would only add that for the null values I needed to add `types` parameter representing a structure of my `data` object. So in my case it would be ` types: {rows: [{
                id: 'STRING',
                country: 'STRING'
            }]},`
otherwise I would get error ` Parameter types must be provided for null values via the 'types' field in query options.`. Other than that it worked fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Also the most important thing that probably got me running in circles in the first place is that I was originally developing the project in TypeScript and it would give me an error in this line `const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);` saying that `options` object is in the wrong format and `Types of property 'types' are incompatible`. I would then try to reformat the options while the solution would be just to use `//@ts-ignore`. Probably some bug in their TS types library.

Comment: I am glad you solved your issue. You are very welcome :)